# Pass ARG to Dockerfile from GitHub composite action?

Tags: dockerfile, github-actions

Saw this, [How to set a Dockerfile ARG in Github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051284/how-to-set-a-dockerfile-arg-in-github-actions) but I am using a composite action and so this syntax does not appear to be available to me (ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions).

So how do I pass an ARG to the Dockerfile (build Docker image stage) and not the "run image/CMD"?

Answer (score 0):

- Example of 1 ARG: docker build --build-arg="VARIABLE=value" .
- Example of 2+ ARG: docker build --build-arg="VARIABLE=value" --build-arg="VARIABLIE=value" .

You simply add on more --build-arg, parameters for the command